# Disable form filter using expression MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, expression

So on one form I have a button than opens a filtered form based on a combobox on the previous form. Works fine. But on the opened form I also have combobox for selecting records - which doesn't work when the form is filtered. I would want to disable the filter when user selects record in that combobox.

Is there a way to disable the form filter using expression in onChange event?

For example:

```
=[FilterOn]=False
```

or

```
=[Filter]=""
```

These don't work for me though.
Thanks

Comment: `Me.FilterOn = False` and `Me.Filter = ""`

Comment: Not through an expression but setting the properties in code as shown above.

Comment: I know it can be done this way in VBA but was hoping to do it using expression for separate reasons. But if it cannot be done then so be it. Thanks

Comment: The event would have to call a VBA Function and in the Function is code to set properties.

Comment: @June7 So I put the code inside VBA sub procedure and it works. When I select something from the combobox the filter cancels but the form doesn't change to the record selected. I have to click it second time for it to happen. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Start a question on that issue and post your code. I have never used OnChange event. I would use AfterUpdate.

Comment: Nevermind running it in AfterUpdate before the rest solved it. My bad, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be an expression like that in event property. Could build a VBA custom public function with code to neutralize filter and call function in event property. It would be complicated because have to pass form name or form object as argument of function `=ClearFilter("formnamehere")`. I have not developed function code and really don't think this is best approach.

In most cases, when OnChange event is used, really should be AfterUpdate.